# Translation of articles from english to hindi with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

Actually I am developing an application for converting articles from english to hindi. So I want to know is it possible to convert strings from english to hindi in jquery.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/translate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. you may try to make use of http://translate.google.com/
Hindi is not a very common language and most of the people don't even have the needed fonts to read it!

Comment: yeah it's only spoken by 1 billion people ! which planet are you from ?

Comment: yeah about 30% of the population, number decreasing every day.

Comment: forgot to add you don't need no hindi fonts nor have your keyboard set to output  हिन्दी to be able to read a webpage in  हिन्दी; learn about languages on the web/utf-8 before making so uneducated answers !

Answer (score 0):

you can put this line of text in your header and it'll embed  gooogle translate  on your page

```
      <a href="http://translate.google.com/translate?u=%lookup~url:current%">Translation</a>
```

that'll translate it for you

Comment: actually I am getting respose in json which consists of english article. Now I want to present it in hindi to my user without showing him the background process.

Comment: visit https://translate.google.com/manager/website/ for a website translator gadget - it gives more code than i have given above the above might be deprecated.